# Transform product attributes to tags

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've about 2000 product attributes and I think that this can cause a problem in my website. I'd like to transform product attributes to tags. And than delete all attributes from my db. Obviously I need to keep all relationship to products. Does someone know how can I do this via mysql?

Comment: show some existing structures and queries.

Comment: Someone suggest me to use this query to delete attributes DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%');
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%';
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id not IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);     but it deletes attributes value, not attributes. I'd like to transform attributes name to tag and than delete attributes name, value and relationship to my db